# Idle time in Chrome Performance tool

Tags: performance, google-chrome, telerik

While analyzing my sites  in performance tool,

- I see ,there is a difference in Localhost and test environment a page  loading time
- The main difference was idle (4800 ms difference) and  that  takes a
  long time to load  page
  (attached the test scenario) whose loading time is longer.
  If you can suggest me what is the idle stands for and its cause .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxOAK.png)

Comment: If you load a page from localhost the data does not travel the internet (all the way from the host of your site) but is served from your computer locally. This is naturally much faster. Or am I missing something? The idle time is when your browser is not doing anything, if your site files travel a long time and the browser is not doing anything during that time it could be that this is calculated as idle time.

Comment: data means, are you referring data getting from API ?I took the same one which is used in test env but that  didn't make any difference.From the Chrome performance I can see while loading page ,a scripting activity (eg: readystatechanged) got fired then  there is an idle time of 5333.6 ms then the next actitivity UpdateLayerTree) got fired

Comment: Not just data gotten from API, but your html, css, and js application files.

Comment: oh but this is the problem with one page where I have used Telerik RadWizard with render type active ,and other page works fine with no such amount of idle in between.